# Unable to drag event between time slots

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I do not understand why I cannot drag events between time slots but can between resources.

I have the interaction plugin and when I drag an event between resources I get the info I need to make the changes, works fine.  If I try and drag the event out of its time slot to another the event doesn't drag at all. I have checked the documentation and looked at the examples but I am obviously missing something.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Meeting Manager</title>


  <link href='/fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='/fullcalendar/timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='/fullcalendar/resource-timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../css/maincj.css' rel='stylesheet' />

  <script src='/fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
  <script src='/fullcalendar/interaction/main.js'></script>
  <script src='/fullcalendar/timeline/main.js'></script>
  <script src='/fullcalendar/resource-common/main.js'></script>
  <script src='/fullcalendar/resource-timeline/main.js'></script>

  <script src='/fullcalendar/moment/main.js'></script>

  <script src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src='../js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

  <script src='../js/moment.min.js'></script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
      plugins: ['interaction', 'moment', 'resourceTimeline'],
      titleFormat: { month: 'long', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', weekday: 'long' },
      selectable: true,
      aspectRatio: 1.6,
      editable: true, // handles for editing event
      dropable: true,
      slotDuration: '00:15',
      resourceAreaWidth: "20%",
      minTime: '08:00',
      maxTime: '18:00',
      header: {
        left: 'today prev,next createRoom',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
      select: (info) => {

        const addMeeting = info;
        const room = addMeeting.resource.id

        $('#resourceId').val(room);
        $('#meetingTitle').val("");
        $('#date').val(moment(addMeeting.start).format('DD'));
        $('#sHour').val(moment(addMeeting.startStr).format('HH'));
        $('#sMinute').val(moment(addMeeting.startStr).format('mm'));
        $('#eHour').val(moment(addMeeting.endStr).format('HH'));
        $('#eMinute').val(moment(addMeeting.endStr).format('mm'));
        $('#host').val("");
        $('#hostDetails').val("");
        $('#bookedBy').val("");
        $('#eventClickModal').modal('show');

        $('#createupdateMeeting').on('click', function () {
          if ($('#meetingTitle').val().length > 1 &&
            $('#host').val().length > 1 &&
            $('#hostDetails').val().length > 1 &&
            $('#bookedBy').val().length > 1) {
            const today = moment();
            const start = today.format('YYYY') + '-' + today.format('MM') + '-' + $('#date').val() + ' ' +
              $('#sHour').val() + ':' + $('#sMinute').val();
            const end = today.format('YYYY') + '-' + today.format('MM') + '-' + $('#date').val() + ' ' +
              $('#eHour').val() + ':' + $('#eMinute').val();
            const update = {
              resourceId: room,
              meetingDate: $('#date').val(),
              start: start,
              end: end,
              title: $('#meetingTitle').val(),
              hostName: $('#host').val(),
              hostContactDetails: $('#hostDetails').val(),
              bookedBy: $('#bookedBy').val(),
            };
            const options = {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(update)
            };

            fetch('/meetingNew', options);
            $('#eventClickModal').modal('hide');
            console.log(update.resourceId);
          }
        });

      },
      eventDrop: async (event) => {
        // if (!event.newResource === null) alert('did not move resource');
        // console.log(event.newResource.id, event.oldResource.id);

        // TODO
      },
      customButtons: {
        createRoom: {
          text: 'New room',
          click: function () {
            $('#id').val();
            $('#title').val();
            $('#occupancy').val();
            $('#resourceClickModal').modal('show');

            $('#createupdateRoom').on('click', async (e) => {
              if ($('#title').val().length > 2 && $('#occupancy').val().length > 0) {
                const update = {
                  title: $('#title').val(),
                  occupancy: $('#occupancy').val()
                }
                const options = {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify(update)
                };
                const response = await fetch('/addRoom', options);
                const data = response.json();
                $('#resourceClickModal').modal('hide');
              }
            });
          }
        }
      },
      aspectRatio: 4,
      events: '/eventsJSON/',
      resourceColumns: [
        {
          labelText: 'Room',
          field: 'title'
        },
        {
          labelText: 'PAX',
          field: 'occupancy',
          width: 40
        },
        {
          labelText: 'Display',
          field: 'id',
          width: 60
        },
      ],
      resources: '/roomsJSON/',
      resourceRender: function (renderInfo) {
        renderInfo.el.addEventListener("click", function () {
          $('#id').val(renderInfo.resource.id);
          $('#title').val(renderInfo.resource.title);
          $('#occupancy').val(renderInfo.resource.extendedProps.occupancy);
          $('#resourceClickModal').modal('show');
        });
        $('#createupdateRoom').on('click', async () => {
          if ($('#title').val().length > 2 && $('#occupancy').val().length > 0) {

            const update = {
              id: $('#id').val(),
              title: $('#title').val(),
              occupancy: $('#occupancy').val()
            }
            const options = {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(update)
            };

            const response = await fetch('/roomUpdate', options);
            const data = response.json();
            $('#resourceClickModal').modal('hide');
            calendar('refetchEvents');
          }
        });
      }
    });


    calendar.render();
  });
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't even allow events to be dragged at all. Please try to make us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your issue. otherwise it's pretty much impossible to tell where you've gone wrong.

Comment: P.S. if you include `editable: true` to allow editing along with the code above, then the dragging works as intended. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jONzLGQ?&editable=true&editors=001 . If you've got some other code which is preventing that, you'll have to show it to us before we can fix it.

Comment: Apologies, I tried not to clutter with too much code. I have edited my question above and posted the code. Thank you for your help

Comment: Still can't reproduce it, even using your code: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gOYeXNg?&editable=true&editors=001 . Are you setting some options on your actual resource or event data related to their ability to be edited?

Comment: I have just replaced the event and resource data to test using arrays as per the docs but I have the same problem. I can drag across resources but not time slots.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then. Perhaps you can play about with my CodePen, adding/removing things (e.g. other JS libs or CSS maybe, or using your own data) and make a version which actually reproduces the issue. Until / unless you can do that then I think unfortunately I can't help you. As far as I can see nothing you've shown so far leads us to the cause of your issue.

Comment: Many thanks for the CodePen. This will help me to try and find what I have done wrong.